# Jquery on click event not working after infinitescroll

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm using the cakephp framework and the jquery infinitescroll plugin for loading the content dynamically. And each post has a link with an ajax action.

When a load the page there are 5 posts and the ajax links are working fine.
But when a load 5 other posts with the infitescroll (ajax) the ajax link is not working.

It looks that the ajax function cannot find the id of the link but I don't find a solution.

```
 <a href="/questions" onclick="return false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right" id="581617"></i></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).on("click","#581617",function(){
        $.ajax({url: "the_url", 
                    type:'post',
           })   });
    </script>
```

UPDATE: After making changes based on @ZacharyKniebel's solution, I am trying to write my selector to attach to links by ID using the below, which is not working. Can anyone tell me why?

```
"a > i.glyphicon.<?php echo $linkId;?>"
```

Comment: Are you appending multiple elements with the same `id`?

Comment: No, I'm generating unique id's.

Comment: well, your jquery is targeting a single id. Perhaps you could adjust your click handler to be in a wider scope than `#581617` (which by the way is not a valid id, ids need to start with a letter) and then in your click handler function check if the id of the target element is valid and/or would work before doing the `$.ajax`

Comment: I have added a letter at the start of the id. I'm not a javascript expert so can you help me how to check if the id is valid. A link to more information is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your delegating your handler just for the element with id `#581617`. Instead, try delegating your handler to more broadly look for your `a > i.glyphicon.glyphicon-circle-arrow-right` elements:

```
$(document).on("click","a > i.glyphicon.glyphicon-circle-arrow-right",function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "the_url", 
        type:'post'
    });   
});
```

As a side-note, in the above I also removed the trailing comma after `type:'post'` for sake of IE functionality. Although keeping the trailing comma is technically valid, IE doesn't like it very much.

**UPDATE:**

With regards to the selector that you are now trying to use, note that you can't have the selector work for all newly loaded links if you are selecting them by ID. There are workarounds that technically could do this, but they're incredible dirty and have awful performance. This is because IDs are unique and binding this handler by ID is like trying to bind to each link individually, instead of binding to all of the links at once. (Technically, since this is a delegated handler, you're not really binding to the links, but you are listening for them).

In short, the selector that I gave you, above, is what you want to use to make your event handler listen for all of them.

Comment: Thank you both for the quick response. It's late in Belgium so I'm gone test this out tomorrow.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and its working but... I have more links with the same class (glyphicon..) so when I press one link more action are executed. So I need to add  a linkId with php (see edit of my post). And then the links are not working anymore.

Comment: The selector that you are looking to use isn't feasible. I have updated my post with more detail.

Comment: Ow, that's a pity. Every link has to peform an other action so then I need to  find an other way. But not that easy so you say.  And maybe it was not that clear: suppose I load (with ajax) 5 new post with each a link. Then there are also 5 new javascripts

Comment: Also, this is now a different question than the original. You should accept this answer, as it solved your original question, and you should make a new question for the next bit.